# Laid off. Should I contact clients from on-going projects?

Tags: clients

I was working with a client for the past year on a site. I was let go from my company.

I don't like the idea of just disappearing. I'd like to contact the client and tell them I've left, and that it was good working them, etc.

Comment: Which country is this in? Opposite recommendations may be appropriate in different countries.

Comment: Sent any PEOPLE at the client that you know well an linked-in request, ideally with an truthful recommendation.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No. They were not "your" clients, but rather clients of your former employer. Let your former employer make contact with them and explain who will be handling their projects/accounts going forward.

Attempting to contact those clients yourself, if your former employer got wind of it, could be construed as you attempting to steal business from your former employer or use that connection to get a job with them which might violate a contract or other agreement you signed. A bit far-fetched, but some people can get really litigious these days.

If those clients contact you afterward, just tell them it was a pleasure working with them and you're disappointed that you're no longer working with them.

Comment: ... and that you are sorry that you were not able to say goodbye or to conclude the matters with them, but that you hope that your company handled everything to their satisfaction.  Take the high road.

Comment: Been there with my last employer.  Everything ended amicably on both sides and I hope I'm remembered fondly but they asked that I not tell their clients I was leaving during my notice period and I didn't.  It's business, people understand, agree with @alroc, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: Depends upon your joining contract if there was no contract which i doubt do whatever you wish but if there was some then stay away from clients till cool off period.

Comment: Is this country-specific? While I do not have any first-hand experience with that situation, various people in Germany have told me on various occasions how they did exactly what the OP suggested. Resources such as [this](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/bei-jobwechsel-sich-von-den-kunden-verabschieden), [this](http://spruchtipps.de/abschiedsmail-an-kunden-kostenlose-vorlagen-und-tipps/) and [this](http://www.aachener-zeitung.de/ratgeber/bildung-beruf/beim-jobwechsel-abschiedsmail-an-geschaeftspartner-nicht-vergessen-1.661040) strongly suggest it is downright rude *not* to contact *long-term* ..

Comment: ... clients when leaving a position there, and as it will reflect badly on the previous employer (by confusing customers and partially destroying the "connection of trust" established by constant interaction with a particular contact person), it is fully in the interest of the previous employer that the departing employee announces their change to customers.

Comment: And with that said, in my experience, I have seen several instances of support staff in user forums of U.S.-based companies say good-bye to the regular "customers" and announce their future unavailability, in both situations (being fired, and leaving on their own initiative). Are you sure your suggestion is even commonly accepted across all contexts in the U.S.?

Comment: "going forward" #ugh

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to bring up the subject of linkedin (other sites are available).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I read all three links you posted and I disagree with your assessment. I think that all three links are from the perspective that you haven't left your current company yet. One of the answers in your first link even says that you shouldn't contact them after you no longer work there.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok: In that case, it depends on how far the "I was let go from my company." by the OP has already progressed. Have they already left their company, or have they just been told that they cannot be employed any longer and thus have a few weeks or months of notice period to go, during which they are supposed to "wrap up unfinished business" and ensure a smooth transition of any open processes to whoever will take over? That is currently not specified in the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I disagree again. OP said "I was let go" and "I've left". That's not ambiguous. Ultimately even if he's still employed he shouldn't contact the company's clients without talking to management first.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok: Do you agree that, from the perspective of the customer, it seems extremely rude if the customer has been in touch with a specific contact person for an extended period of time, and suddenly the customer gets a notification by someone unknown that someone else will handle their requests from now on?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You as an employee are hired by your employer, not the customer. If your company decides that you are not to notify the customers that you worked with (believe it or not, it happened at my last job when I put in my two-weeks notice), then that's what you do. If they give you the option, then I agree. Notifying the customers is a professional courtesy.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok: I agree, if the company specifically asks the parting/former employee to not say good bye to long-term business contacts, you have a point. Otherwise, basic rules of politeness and social behaviour apply.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that should have happened _before_ the employer left the company, and it is the responsibility of the employers boss to decide how it is to happen.

Answer (score 27):

In my view, you don't only have a business connection with people you've worked with, you have a personal connection with them as well. It's natural that you want to say goodbye to people you've worked with for a year.

There are two things to look out for:

- Let your employer inform them first, so that they can tell the client who will be taking up your work, who is their new contact, that sort of thing. It may be that you are the one who gets to inform them anyway, but let your employer decide.
- Don't actively try to steal the client. Besides possible restrictions in contracts, it's not really the ethical thing to do.

Other than that, I don't see a problem.

(other people say that culture may matter here, I am in the Netherlands)

Comment: The problem is with doing it behind the employer's back.

Comment: @reinierpost - they are not your employer anymore, and you don't report to them.

Comment: @reinierpost: it's only talking to someone, the employer will have to live with the fact that people do that... I mean, you're _at least_ going to link with such people on LinkedIn etc anyway.

Comment: If your former customers want to find you after you quit, there's not much to prevent them anyway. But there's a huge difference between being listed on LinkedIn and writing them an email saying "I'll be available for contracting after termination". And there's another huge difference between writing that email from your private account to a customer you've worked with intimately for several months, and sending that email to all everybody you've ever had contact with from your former company's email address.

Comment: I agree that "I'll be available for contracting" is over the line, that's actively trying to steal the client. Sending a LinkedIn mail with a message saying "it was nice to have worked with you, let's connect, maybe one day we'll meet again" shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: And he's specifically asking about a client for which he's worked on site for the last year. That's rather different from "everybody you've eve had contact with".

Comment: This is the best answer. You are a person, not a robot. As a human, it is natural to gain some sort of "friendly" feelings with customers if you spend any significant time working with them. So there's nothing wrong with saying "goodbye" to people that you'd like to say goodbye to, even if your employer asks you not to. Once again, you aren't a robot, you aren't a slave, you are a human being entitled to develop relationships with other human beings. Even if that relationship is just a work relationship, it is still a connection on some level. Saying goodbye is just polite.

Comment: @reiner:For an employer to not expect you to say goodbye to people you have worked with while in their employ is just ridiculous. It's not doing anything "behind their back" because they should already expect for it to happen. It's another matter if you are contacting clients and making it explicit that you are soliciting their business. Otherwise, it is just being polite and remaining on good terms with people you have worked with. You run into the same people time and again throughout your career and if you want to leave a good impression of yourself you won't just disappear without goodbye.

Comment: +1 but I disagree that it's remotely unethical; he was laid off by the company he owes than nothing that is not legally specified.

Comment: Contacting your former employer's clients after you're employment has ended is a terrible idea.  You can get yourself into trouble doing this, and it will make your former employer nervous.   I once worked at a company that laid off some PMs, and one of them had client #s in their personal cell phone, called them and said "you're screwed, they just let me go and I'm the only one that knows what's going on with your project."  Even if the OP doesn't do this, the employer might feel the need to operate under the assumption that is what was said.

Comment: @Andy: an employer would be pretty damn paranoid if he felt the need to operate under such an assumption. As I mentioned, most people would connect on Linkedin with clients, and that's more than just sending a message. And anyway, how on earth could you get yourself into trouble?

Comment: Look at some of the other answers, but for one it might be explicitly spelled out in your contract.  I'd be hesitant to connect with clients on LinkedIn, and employers may frown on that as well.

Comment: You're laid off, the contract is at an end.

Answer (score 12):

If the situation is that you have an end of employment date set up ahead of time but you're expected to keep working in the meantime, THEN it could be a breach of contract to reveal that you're being laid off.  So definitely don't say anything in that case.

So that's the part of my answer that's new, below is the rest of my answer in the form of rebuttals to existing answers.

"No. They were not "your" clients, but rather clients of your former employer."

The company I work for exclusively does contract work for other companies.  The way that our contracts work, we are employees of the company where our offices are (the company I would casually say I work for), but also legally employees of the clients whose projects we work on.  So, in a very real and LEGAL sense, my clients are my clients.  We have no way of knowing the legal circumstances of the OP's situation, so the above assertion is baseless.

"Attempting to contact those clients yourself, if your former employer got wind of it, could be construed as you attempting to steal business from your former employer or use that connection to get a job with them which might violate a contract or other agreement you signed."

I work in the US, so of course this may be different where you are, but here any such non-compete clauses are generally a joke.  They have never held up in court.  The legal basis for this is that once you are laid off or quit, you are no longer under contract with that employer.  And no matter how your employer tries to construe the language of your work contract, one of the most fundamental aspects of contract law is that any involved party can back out of the contract at any time.  Your former employer can claim that the contract covers say, a one year period after you leave the company, during which time you can't work for their competitors.  You of course can then say, "Well I'm backing out of the contract now, so too bad for you."

"Don't actively try to steal the client. Besides possible restrictions in contracts, it's not really the ethical thing to do."

Since I've already covered the contract aspect, let's look at the ethical concerns.  You and that company were engaged in a mutually beneficial working relationship.  That relationship has ended.  Your former employer is not a human being with whom you are still friends.  Ethically speaking you own your former employer NOTHING, just as they owe you nothing after you leave.

I don't like that people keep using the word "steal" here, as that is literally not applicable.  The client isn't a small physical object you can sneakily slip into your pocket and walk away with.  It is literally not possible to steal one of your former employer's clients.  What you CAN potentially do is engage that client in a risk/reward discussion with regards to hiring/contracting you to work for their company.  But that is no different from any other person trying to get a job.  That's just how the process works.

---

*edit: "The only thing this doesn't cover is burning your bridges. It could be a very real disadvantage to piss off your former employer or coworkers." –  Tim Seguine

I feel like Tim raised a good point in so far as I should have addressed this.  I'd like to try to do that now, but I've been finding it difficult to express what feels very self-evident to me.  So first let me re-iterate what I said before that you DEFINITELY should NOT reveal to your client that you're being laid off before your company does.  You're still under contract and most likely there's privacy clauses, and it would just be asking for trouble.  But assuming you wait until after your company makes the announcement, and assuming that you will wait until after you've left the company to make your good byes IF the situation plays out that way... then I couldn't come up with any plausible scenario where you're burning any bridges or pissing people off.

So as much as I'd like to cover this "issue" it seems unrealistic to me.  It may just be the combination of the country I live in and the industry in which I work.  Maybe non-compete clauses are a big deal where you live.  Maybe your company has a long dark history of suing former employees for "violating" non-competes.  If you know that to be a fact, then I guess you have to decide for yourself how you feel about that.

But let me paint a picture for you one last time.  Your company is laying you off.  However, the word "company" is just a label we use identify a group of people working together under some government charter, blah blah blah.  The point is that there were actual people involved in the decision to lay you off.  Your direct supervisor, plus probably your supervisor's manager, plus a couple of HR reps, plus who knows who else.  Unless your company is very small, there was a whole chain people involved in making this decision.  Those people are the ones who might be pissed off if you were to go work directly for their client.  Do you think that THEY were concerned that laying you off was "burning bridges"?  Those people got together and decided that the best decision for their organization as a whole, was to kick you out of it.  Are you really going to concern yourself with how those people feel about YOUR CAREER after you leave?

Comment: The only thing this doesn't cover is burning your bridges. It could be a very real disadvantage to piss off your former employer or coworkers.

Comment: @TimSeguine How does it matter? He is laid off. Who cares for their former employers, after getting sacked? BTW I like this answer

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you are still in your notice period. If that's not the case, you really shouldn't write such an email.

But if you are still working for the company, it's perfectly fine to send such an email as long as you atleast include a sentense with helpfull information about how the relationship between them and your company will be in the future (like introducing your replacement, giving his contact information, saying that your email adress will be dead in a week, etc.), because this will make the email a business matter.

Writing a 100% personal farewell letter is indeed (as others already said) somewhat a no-go. Also you will want to use your business email for sending that message. Sending it from a private email would really be a no-go again.

If you want to be sure, you could simply ask your manager if you are allowed to write such an email. Of course in that discussion with your manager you will want to highlight the fact, that it's in a strong interest of your company that the clients are informed about what's going on, because that's the professional way.

Comment: Notice period?  He was laid off, he didn't resign.  I assume he isn't there anymore.

Comment: @tcrosley I think that depends on the locale, which isn't given in the question. For example notice periods for layoffs are atleast 4 weeks (and up to 7 month) in any EU member state.

Comment: Thanks, my ignorance.  In his post, the OP said he was "let go", and I mistakenly assumed that meant he'd left already.

Answer (score 0):

Legally, you'd probably need to check your contract.

Ethically, no... to a point.

This actually recently happened to my father.

He joined a pretty large well known company about 25 years ago. When he joined the contracts in place didn't have any clauses about taking clients upon leave. He worked there for ~25 years and when they decided to get rid of him they finally asked him to sign a new contract regarding this (he wasn't obligated to sign). Since he joined the new contracts had clauses added about that type of thing, but he was still bound by the one he signed decades before.

According to him, a lot of his clients just wanted him to do the work for them, and weren't interested in other people at the company doing the same work. I think in the end he came to an arrangement with the company that he would only take a select number of clients, and probably got a payout for doing so.